# ajax url call to the file inside folder

Tags: ajax, file, call

i have JavaScript function calling doing Ajax call.

```
inside- sales.php
```

below is the code

```
strURl="sample.php";
self.xmlHttpReq.open('GET',strlURL,true);
```

Since both the files is in the same path it is calling.

i want the `sample.php` to be inside the folder called model

so how to rewrite the strUrl so that it fectches inside this folder.

please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You just add the folder name before file name.

```
strURl="model/sample.php";
self.xmlHttpReq.open('GET',strlURL,true);
```

Thanks